# IntraWeb ISAPI Module throws "Unrecognized Command" Error on IIS 7

Tags: delphi, iis-7, isapi, intraweb

I am trying to configure an IIS7 web server to run my IntraWeb 10 application.
I followed the steps described by [Dr. Bob](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinC3.htm) and [Chau Chee Yang](http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2009/10/configure-windows-7-iis7-for-isapi-dll.html).

The application starts but results in an error: **Unrecognized Command: : WEB:**.

(Web seems to be the name of the virtual directory used - I tried different ones and the message changes corresponding to that).

Looks like the virtual directories name is passed as a parameter to the ISAPI DLL...

The same DLL runs nicely on a web server with an older IIS (6 i guess).

Is there a configuration option that could cause/remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague solved it for me. He did this by removing everything I did and configuring the web sever from scratch again.

I suppose the problem was configuring the `Handler Mappings` on the wrong level of the tree.
But I'm not entirely sure about it. (The IntraWeb-DLL is assigned on the top level now)